# Why $scope variable isn't updated?

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with a scope variable. When i open the form, the content is displayed correctly in the input field. But when I change them and the ok-function fires the changes are not displayed. instead i get the content of form.name. Why isnt the scope updated by the ng-model of the input field?

```
app.controller('updateFormCtrl', function( $scope, $modalInstance, APIService, form) {

    $scope.name = form.name;


$scope.ok = function() {

    alert($scope.name)

};

});
```

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-10"><input ng-model="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Categorie"></div>
```

Edit: Here is the other controller:

```
$scope.updateForm = function( form ) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({

            templateUrl: 'views/modals/updateForm.html',
            controller: 'updateFormCtrl',
            resolve: {

                form: function() { 

                    return form;

                }

            }

        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function() {

            $scope.categories =  APIService.query({ route:'category' });

        });
    };
```

Edit 2:

```
 <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Abbrechen</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Speichern</button>

    </div><!-- /.modal-footer -->
```

Comment: What is `form`? Can you add your service?

Comment: Where is $scope.ok being called?

Comment: I have updated start post. When I {{name}} the content is show correctly, but the update isn't done :( Is there a problem with ng-model="name" and $scope.name when changing the model? the update only works in the view...not in the controller :(

Comment: its a bootstrap ui directive http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: Where is the ok() function defined ? Is it not in the updateFormCtrl ? It should be there.

Comment: hmm...he is in the updateFormCtrl...i only copied the code wrong. sorry for this mistake...my code is like this exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/6PYNn/8/ only the scope.test content comes from the resolve function. and on alert I don't get the updated content

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `$scope.ok` isn't defined inside `updateFormCtrl`. So basically, your `ok()` cannot read the changes you have made in textbox.

Try moving `$scope.ok` inside controller.

```
app.controller('updateFormCtrl', function( $scope, $modalInstance, APIService, form) {

$scope.name = form.name;
$scope.ok = function() {

alert($scope.name)
```

};

});

Comment: the ok() function is defined in the update form controler, it was just a copy mistake!

Comment: with ok(name) i can access the correct properties of name...but $scope.name isn't updated :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution:

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot